# Why `. test.sh` take the same effect such as `./test.sh`?

Tags: bash

```
cd  /tmp
vim  test.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "test me"
```

I have edited a file named  `test.sh`.

```
./test.sh
test me
```

The `.` means current directory which is `/tmp` here, `./test.sh` can execute it.
Why  `.    test.sh` can execute it too,there are several blank whitespace between  `.`  and `test.sh`?

```
.   test.sh
test me
```

Comment: `.` is the command [called `dot` in the POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot). Bash also has it available under the name `source`. It's not referring to the local directory, in your usage -- it's referring to the shell builtin.

Comment: ...contrary to the test described in the question, it's not actually the same as `./test.sh`; try something like `cd /` in the script -- when you dot it, you'll see that it changes your parent interpreter's directory (because the commands in the script were run *inside that preexisting interpreter*, not in a shell started as a child process).